# Group cohomology of free abelian groups

Tags: group-cohomology

I am looking for a good reference for the structure of the cohomology ring $H^*(Z^n,Z)$.  In particular,  I would like to know how large is the subgroup of $H^2(Z^n,Z)$ generated by cup-products from $H^1(Z^n,Z)$.

I will be grateful for any help!

Comment: The group cohomology of $\mathbb{Z}^n$ with trivial coefficients agrees with the cohomology of its classifying space, which is the $n$-torus $T^n$. So the cohomology is the exterior algebra on $H^1$.

Comment: The Kunneth formula holds here by abstract nonsense, and the cross product maps are isomorphisms because $H^1(\mathbb{Z}, \mathbb{Z}) = H^1(S^1, \mathbb{Z})$ is torsion-free.